# Length of diagonal compared to the limit of lengths of stair-shaped curves converging to it

Tags: geometry, limits, fake-proofs, arc-length

[image]

I see this post and I am stunned. I think this is fallacious but I can't figure where is the fallacy?

If you know the fallacy. Please post a answer.

Comment: In-spirit duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/12906/23353

Answer (score 0):

The measurement of the jaggy lines is not the sum of the distances between points. It's the measurement of jagged triangular jags.  Or in other words measuring the sum of the x and y offsets.  As the curve converges into a line segment the  calculation we are making is still *not* measuring the distance between points.  It's always measuring the x and y offsets.  When the jags are infinitesimal so that they become co-linear we have not defined our procedure to be anything resembling measuring the distance.  Our procedure does not change into something else just because we are now on a line.  Our procedure remains measuring the x and y offsets.  It was *never* measuring the distance between points.