# Hausdorff dimension of the Koch curve

Tags: real-analysis, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

It is well known that the Hausdorff dimension of the Koch curve is $\log_34\approx1.26>1$. Thus by the property of Hausdorff measure, $\forall1<p<1.2$, the $p$-Hausdorff measure of the Koch curve is $\infty$. On the other hand, the Koch curve consists of countably many line segments, whose $p$-Hausdorff measure is $0$, leading to the conclusion $p$-Hausdorff measure of the Koch curve is $0$. It seems to be a contradiction. Am I missing something? I am confused by my thoughts.

Comment: "The Koch curve consists of countably many line segments."  This is false.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake

Comment: You might find the answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005409/koch-curve-from-cantor-sets-paradox helpful.

Comment: Thank you all! Now I know where I am wrong in defining the Koch curve.